# Pig Latin fetching first field

Tags: apache-pig

I have below pig code for a sample file.

```
001,Rajiv,Reddy,21,9848022337,Hyderabad
002,siddarth,Battacharya,22,9848022338,Kolkata
003,Rajesh,Khanna,22,9848022339,Delhi
004,Preethi,Agarwal,21,9848022330,Pune
```

I load the above file using PIG load command & then loop thru it and get 2,3 fields as follows.

```
students = LOAD '/user/4965056e873066f2abe966b4129918/Pig_Data/students.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,fname:chararray,lname:chararray,age:int,mob:chararray,city:chararray);
each1 = foreach students generate (id,fname,lname);
```

output of each1:
   `((001,Rajive,reddy))` etc.

Now i wanna get 1st field of `each1` i.e.`ID` how to get it. I tried below code but showing error

```
each2 = foreach each1 generate(students.id)
```

Need to get the first filed from `each2` relation.

Comment: generate is a keyword so add a space like this each2 = foreach each1 generate students.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra parenthesis are added to the `each1` relation, simply remove them:

```
students = LOAD '/user/4965056e873066f2abe966b4129918/Pig_Data/students.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,fname:chararray,lname:chararray,age:int,mob:chararray,city:chararray);
each1 = foreach students generate id,fname,lname;
```

And you will get something like :

```
(001,Rajive,reddy)
```

For the `each2` relation, you can get any filed of `each1` without using the qualifier `students`, use filed name or filed position like this :

```
each2 = foreach each1 generate id;
each2 = foreach each1 generate $0;
```

And you will get something like :

```
(001)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
each2 = foreach each1 generate $0;
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12791529)

Comment: The OP asked the question "i wanna get 1st field of each1 i.e.ID how to get it". The code snippet I have provided above will retrieve the first field from "each1". I am not sure why this does not qualify as an answer. If it turns out to be not working then it will be incorrect but I would wait for OP to confirm that.